# How would I replace these icons with text instead?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have 3 letter acronyms in the circles instead of icons. Here is the [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/hadarweiss/pen/WvEXeK).

```
%nav.menu
  %input#menu-toggler.menu-toggler{:type => "checkbox", :checked => "checked"}
  %label{:for => "menu-toggler"}
  %ul
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-facebook{:href => "https://www.facebook.com/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-google{:href => "https://www.google.com/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-dribbble{:href => "https://dribbble.com/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-codepen{:href => "https://codepen.io/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-linkedin{:href => "https://www.linkedin.com/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-github{:href => "https://github.com/", :target => "_blank"}
    %li.menu-item
      %a.fa.fa-github{:href => "https://github.com/", :target => "_blank"}
```

Comment: I don't see any HTML in your question. Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the classes and insert the letter after the '}'

```
%li.menu-item
      %a{:href => "https://www.facebook.com/", :target => "_blank"} A
```